# Updating label during function

Tags: swift

If you have a simple routine like the one below how do you get the label to update during the loop? When I run this it only updates at the end when the function it is in completes.

```
for loop in 1...10 {
    doCalculation()

    resultLabel.text = String(result)

    sleep(1)
}

function doCalculation() {

    ... perform calculation updating variable result ...

}
```

I have tried this also but this doesn't fix it.

```
for loop in 1...10 {
    doCalculation()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.resultLabel.text = String(self.result)
    }

    sleep(1)
}
```

Comment: Use asyncAfter and recursion, not loop and sleep.

Comment: Or even better, just use a repeating Timer.

Comment: Are you able to explain these ideas a little more. Just starting the move from Objective C to Swift and so new to this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Swift. The answer would be the same in Objective C.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Timer`:

> Swift’s Timer class is a flexible way to schedule work to happen in
>   the future, either just once or repeatedly.

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
    print("Timer fired!")
}
```

The more detailed explanation can be found [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-make-an-action-repeat-using-timer) or [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/117/the-ultimate-guide-to-timer).